# Why I can't organize objects in outliner as I want

Tags: outliner

[image]

[image]

What can I do if I want to organize my outliner as I want?
For an instance, now I would like to have a shuffle to the Light_grp, but I didn't find out a way to do that. And I mean, this should be done by dragging intuitively, isn't it?
It seems to be forced sorted in outliner that I can't do interactions like "move up/down a level" and "move to top/bottom".

And if I can't do that, what's the forced sorting for?

Comment: Ok, I played with the outliner, and it sorts objects a bit randomly at times... :)).
However, what you're asking isn't possible as of yet, only collections can be reordered manually.

Comment: This reminds me of how After Effects Project Panel is sorted, which would force everything sorted in alphabet name order.(Alphabet order seems to be the REAL order, though you could choose Size or Type order, errors might happen in index or selection array especially while you are in scripting)

Comment: Sounds pretty similar. Blender sorts objects by creation date (if you uncheck alphabetically), but it's kind of buggy at times :))